# R - converting a timestamp to a local time and date

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct

How can convert a timestamp to local time and date?

I have tried the following options for this specific timestamp: `1594598065352`:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character('1594598065352'))/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")
x
"2020-07-12 23:54:25 UTC"

x <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character('1594598065352'))/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="DST")
x
"2020-07-12 23:54:25 DST"

x <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character('1594598065352'))/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
x
"2020-07-12 23:54:25 GMT"
```

I get the same result in all options:

```
2020-07-12 23:54:25
```

According to this [timestamp converter page](https://www.epochconverter.com/), I should get this below in my **local time zone**:

```
Monday, 13 July 2020 01:54:25.352 GMT+02:00 DST
```

Any ideas of how I can get this right in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same output in all 3 cases because 1) and 3) are same (UTC and GMT) whereas 2) (DST) is not a valid `tz` value.

If you don't mention the timezone value it should by default give you time in your local time zone.

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric('1594598065352')/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
```

---

Alternatively, you can run `OlsonNames()` in your console to get list of valid timezones in R. `'Etc/GMT-2'` seems to be the one for you.

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric('1594598065352')/1000,origin="1970-01-01", tz = 'Etc/GMT-2')
#[1] "2020-07-13 01:54:25 +02"
```

Comment: got it right now. thank you very much for the answer!